# How to dynamically generate an entire class and concatenate it to its parent selector using LESS

Tags: css, less

So far I have this (LESS language):

**LESS**:

```
.test(@name) {
    (~".sm-@{name}") {
        background: ~"url(../images/icons/sm/@{name}-16x16.png)";
    }
}
```

and I can call it (`.test("facebook")`) to generate something like this:

**CSS**:

```
.sm-facebook {
    background: url(../images/icons/sm/facebook-16x16.png);
}
```

However, I'm not able to concatenate this generated class definition to a parent selector using the usual `&` operator. I would expect

**LESS**:

```
ul {
    li {
        &.test("facebook");
    }
}
```

to generate

**CSS**:

```
ul li.sm-facebook {
    background: url(../images/icons/sm/facebook-16x16.png);
}
```

but I am getting a parse error.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### A LESS 1.4 Answer

At the time of initial answer, I had not resolved if there is a way to do this in LESS 1.3.3 (but later did, see update below). I had found that the current LESS 1.4 (beta) can achieve it by putting the concatenation in the mixin itself this way (note the lack of quotes on the argument):

**LESS**

```
.test(@name) {
    &.sm-@{name} {
        background: ~"url(../images/icons/sm/@{name}-16x16.png)";
    }
}

ul{
  li {
    .test(facebook);
  }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
ul li.sm-facebook {
  background: url(../images/icons/sm/facebook-16x16.png);
}
```

**If you need flexibility** to have it concatenate or not, you can do a nested mixin like so (this one defaults to attach):

```
.test(@name, @attach: 1) {
    .attach(1) {
      &.sm-@{name} {
        background: ~"url(../images/icons/sm/@{name}-16x16.png)";
      }
    }
    .attach(0) {
      .sm-@{name} {
        background: ~"url(../images/icons/sm/@{name}-16x16.png)";
      }
    }
   .attach(@attach);
}
```

Then use it like this `.test(facebook);` to concatenate, and this `.test(facebook, 0);` to separate it as a child (or standalone) class.

### Update: A LESS 1.3.1 to 1.3.3 Answer

Change the name first so that the string evaluation is separate from the class name assignment. Other points made above about flexibility can be used for this answer as well.

```
.test(@name) {
  @addName: ~"sm-@{name}";
  &.@{addName} {
        background: ~"url(../images/icons/sm/@{name}-16x16.png)";
    }
}
```

Comment: Last solution for 1.3.3 works great! I just updated my question since I forgot to put a `~` in front of the string to escape the delimiters; maybe you should update your answer accordingly. Thank you again.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that in my testing too. Updated.